# OpenCL clGetDeviceIDs returns -1 when GPU and 0 when CPU

Tags: opencl, gpu

I was running my OpenCL/C++ code on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (NVIDIA Corporation GM204 [GeForce GTX 980]).
It's working correctly on CPU but `clGetDeviceIDs` method returned -1 when I changed `CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU` to `CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU`.

The code in question:

```
ret = clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id, &ret_num_devices);
cout << ret;
checkError(ret, "clGetDeviceIDs");
```

Outputs -1.

But the following:

```
ret = clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, 1, &device_id, &ret_num_devices);
cout << ret;
checkError(ret, "clGetDeviceIDs");
```

Outputs 0.

Why?

Comment: This should be more a conflict between of your Ubunto OS and some device driver installations, rather than an OpenCL coding problem.

Comment: thx @Christian , and how can I check/solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some modifications depending on the code in [this link](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/498968/printing-all-opencl-devices-not-detecting-all-opencl-devices-under-windows/):

```cpp
cl_int ret = clGetPlatformIDs(2, platforms, &ret_num_platforms);
cout << ret;
//ret = clGetDeviceIDs( platforms[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, 1, &device_id, &ret_num_devices);  // Execute me on CPU
ret = clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[1], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id, &ret_num_devices); // Execute me on GPU
```